# Apache2 with Virtualhosts and Cloudflare are not working

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, virtualhost, cdn

I have a Debian 11 Server with one public IPv4 Address and One Domain. The subdomain mail is defined in a virtual host with a reverse proxy for mailcow. The subdomain mail is also the reverse DNS for the server. The root Domain and www subdomain are configured in a virtual host for my Wordpress Site. All is working fine.
If I enable a proxy like Cloudflare for the root domain and www subdomain, it rewrites all with the content of the subdomain mail. Why doesn't work it with a cdn like cloudflare to show me the right page.
I don't know much about nginx as well as apache2. So would it work with nginx?
I have no idea anymore.

Comment: I would guess this is more of a cloudflare configurtion problem than anything else, but I might also be wrong, cause I've never tried such setup.

Comment: Yes I think also that is a cloudflare setup problem, but I don't where. Do you think it would be work on an nginx server?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that, if I enable Cloudflare proxy on my Domain example.com and Subdomain www. on full (not strict) SSL mode, I got redirect to my mailserver sub domain (mail.), which isn't enabled in Cloudflare as proxy.